# What is scope of session variable scope in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one web application using asp.net with c#
I am creating one session any page as below

```
Session["SessionName"] = "SessionValue";
```

I need to know that I can access this session variable or not in below listed cases

1)  Accessing same web application in new tab of same browser

2)  Accessing same web application in new window of same browser

3)  Accessing same web application in other browser

Thanks

Comment: These seem like experiments you could easily perform yourself in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, yes to #1 and #2; no to #3 (by default, using a cookie to store the session ID).

By default, the Session object is accessed by the session ID that is stored in a cookie. Any requests that can share the same cookie will have the same Session object on the server side code.

If you need your application to work across browsers, read the section on a "cookieless" session https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer before (sorry not enough reputation to comment yet).

If you want the third case to work instead of Session you would have to define a Application variable like this:

```
Application["SomeName"] = "SomeValue";
```

further explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx).

Comment: With the caveat that this value would be shared across all sessions.

Comment: Yeah true in most cases. However its hard to tell what he wants his session variable to do. If it should be modified per session then I agree.

Comment: Thanks to all for sharing knowledge